# TableView not showing any data

Tags: objective-c, ios7, tableview, uitableview

I'm hoping to pick the brain of one of you geniuses on here.  I wanted to teach myself to start creating some more advanced iOS UI views.  So here's what I have:

- A view Controller, top half is a UIImageView and the bottom half has a View Region which holds a TableView
- The TableView has a custom TableViewCell.  I've created properties for my custom TableViewCell
- I've given my TableViewCell a reuse identifier name
- I've added the UITableViewDataSource delegate to my custom View Controller class

Now when I run my program, no data shows.  There are no errors or anything, but no data is showing.

Below is the snippet of code that I have in my View Controller class for testing:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LVGPersonEventTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"personEventTableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.eventDayLabel.text = @"Monday";
    cell.eventMonthDateLabel.text = @"June 18";
    cell.eventVenueNameLabel.text = @"Club Rain";
    cell.eventAddressLabel.text = @"Address....";
    cell.eventTimeLabel.text = @"11PM - 3AM";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you implement `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` for your LVGPersonEventTableViewCell class?

Comment: Did you check the delegate methods are invoked? If they are not invoked, you forgot to set tableview's delegate. `[tableView setDelegate:self]` and `[tableView setDataSource:self]`.

Comment: @trick14 that was the problem!!! It is working now.  Awesome, thanks so much.